# How to count child rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in my sqlite db - tenders and lots.

tenders:

```
id
name
address
```

lots:

```
id
tender_id # it's tender's ID from table `tenders`
summ
```

One tender may have many lots. How to count tenders that have 0 lots?

I tried queries such as:

```
select lots.* from lots
inner join tenders on tenders.id = lots.tender_id
group by lots.id
having count(*) =0
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(tenders.id) AS cnt FROM tenders, lots WHERE lots.tender_id = tenders.id group by tenders.id having cnt=0
```

with no result.
But when I try to do

```
select * from lots where tender_id=263128
```

I see 0 rows as a result.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted and maybe giving a vote ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tenders.id 
FROM tenders 
WHERE tenders.id NOT IN (SELECT tender_id FROM lots)
```

or different amounts of lots:

```
SELECT tenders.id
FROM tenders
WHERE tenders.id IN 
(
SELECT tender_id FROM lots GROUP BY tender_id HAVING COUNT(*) IN (2,3)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But what if I wand to check not only 0 lots? As an example - what tenders have 1 or 2 or >6 rows?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt with a join looks promising, but of course you get no results because you select from lots.

I would do it the other way around and make it a `left join` that way you can check for `null` on lots

```
select
        tenders.id
    from tenders
    left join lots on tenders.id = lots.tender_id
    where lots.tender_id is null
```

Or if you want to check against a specific count of lots per tender:

```
select
        tenders.id
    from tenders
    left join lots on tenders.id = lots.tender_id
    group by tenders.id
    having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Please, see my comment to the message above and tell me how can I change this query to apply new conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Using sub-query:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT COUNT() FROM lots WHERE tender_id=tenders.id) AS LotCount FROM tenders;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,
It will be helpful to you...**

> ```
> SELECT * FROM (
> SELECT T.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lots L WHERE L.empid = T.empid) AS 'RecordFound'  
> FROM tenders AS T) TendersLots
> WHERE RecordFound = 0
> ```

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**